# Get all coordinates used by div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm wondering what's the best way to get all coordinates used by a `<div>`. You can do something like this, but this will only give you the top, left coordinates of the `<div>`.

```
var element = document.getElementById('some-id');
var position = element.getBoundingClientRect();
var x = position.left;
var y = position.top;
```

Comment: It's just math. Get the width & height and add....

Comment: What do you mean by only left and top co-ordinates?

Answer (score 0):

Simply add the width to `x` to find the right position and the height to `y` to find the bottom position:

```
var left = position.left,
    top = position.top,
    right = left + element.clientWidth,
    bottom = top + element.clientHeight;
```